# Get a specific nested child and count it

Tags: java, android, firebase

I making an Attendance App.
In the app there is a function to know how many event an users already attend and what event they attend.

What i want is something like this (i dont know if it work or there is a better way):

```
private void fetchSpecificEvent() {
    //Fetch event that user already attend
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelEvent> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelEvent>()
            .setQuery(referenceForSpecificEvent, snapshot -> new ModelEvent(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("eventID").getValue()).toString(),
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
            )
            .build();
    ...
}

private void getAttendanceCount(){
    //Get how many event user already attend
    referenceForCount.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            attendanceCount = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

The main problem is i dont know what reference i use on: referenceForSpecificEvent and referenceForCount

This the JSON:

[image]

This the full JSON : https://pastebin.com/k65jhMUC

Sorry for the title, i dont know the keyword for it.

Comment: Can you print JSON response instead of this image.

Comment: What exactly from the shared schema would you like to count? Please provide a concrete example? Have you already tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it. Probably not the best (because i cant really explain what i want) but it works.

```
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Attendance");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Get Event ID
                    Log.i(TAG, eventSnapshot.getKey());
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.child(Objects.requireNonNull(eventSnapshot.getKey())).getChildren()) {
                        //Get User ID
                        //Log.i(TAG, userSnapshot.getKey());
                        if(Objects.equals(userSnapshot.getKey(), stringEmail)){
                            intCount++;
                            listEvent.add(eventSnapshot.getKey());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.i(TAG, "No Value Found");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    });
```